# How to get the number of the row that contains a specific value in the given column?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the number of the row that contains a specific value in the given column. It is guaranteed that such value exists in the column and in a unique row.

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
pos = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'pred'])
pos.loc[1,'id'] = [4, 4, 4]
pos.loc[2,'id'] = [2, 3, 3]
pos.loc[3,'id'] = [1, 1, 2]
pos.loc[4,'id'] = [1, 2, 1]

print(pos)

print(pos[pos['id'] == [1, 1, 2]].index[0])
```

I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (6,), (3,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop. If you want the position:

```
next(i for i, x in enumerate(pos['id']) if [1,1,2] == x)
```

Output: `2`

Or, to have the index:

```
next(i for i, x in zip(pos.index, pos['id']) if [1,1,2] == x)
```

Output: `3`

Comment: Worked (the second option). Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, try this:

```
pos[pos.apply(lambda x: x['id'] == [1,1,2], axis=1)].index[0]
```

Output:

```
3
```

OR

```
[i for i, v in zip(pos.index, pos['id']) if v == [1,1,2]][0]
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: `[i for i, v in zip(pos.index, pos['id']) if v == [1,1,2]][0]` is more or less the same as suggested in my answer (except I used `next` since OP mentioned that this value is existing and unique)

Comment: @mozway I like using the `next` here. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `list` in cell, it creates a lot of problem for `pandas`. It will try to do broadcast operation on 4 row and 3 element of list. If you do need an `object` column, using `tuple`:

First try to convert you list column to tuple using

```
pos['id'] = pos['id'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Then you are good to go with your operation

```
print(pos[pos['id'] == tuple([1, 1, 2])].index[0])
```

If you don't want to do this operation I recommend to see answer given by [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78147447/14867730) and [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78147382/14867730), pretty straightforward.